# Edit Range data (timeSeries) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I have range data as follows:

```
    var data1 = [[1388538000000, 1.5, 5.7],
[1388624400000, 2.8, 7.4],
[1388710800000, 2.7, 7.9],
[1388797200000, 3.6, 8.4],
[1388883600000, 4.3, 10.3],
[1388970000000, 4.0, 8.9],
[1389056400000, 4.9, 7.0],
[1389142800000, 3.9, 5.5],
[1389229200000, -0.6, 4.5],
[1389315600000, -0.5, 5.3],
[1389402000000, -0.3, 2.4],
[1389488400000, -6.5, -0.4],
[1389574800000, -7.3, -3.4],
[1389661200000, -7.3, -2.3],
[1389747600000, -7.9, -4.2],
[1389834000000, -4.7, 0.9],
[1389920400000, -1.2, 0.4],
[1390006800000, -2.3, -0.1],
[1390093200000, -2.0, 0.3]]
```

I now want to up-shift each datapoint by 10 and store it in var 'data': for e.g.

```
[1388538000000, 1.5, 5.7] becomes [1388538000000, 11.5, 15.7]
```

How do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Add your code. PS It will involve iterating over the array somehow.

Comment: That's only the last two data-points btw. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes that's what was required, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0;i < data1.length; i++){
    data1[i][1] += 10
    data1[i][2] += 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to generate a modified array

```js
var data1 = [
  [1388538000000, 1.5, 5.7],
  [1388624400000, 2.8, 7.4],
  [1388710800000, 2.7, 7.9],
  [1388797200000, 3.6, 8.4],
  [1388883600000, 4.3, 10.3],
  [1388970000000, 4.0, 8.9],
  [1389056400000, 4.9, 7.0],
  [1389142800000, 3.9, 5.5],
  [1389229200000, -0.6, 4.5],
  [1389315600000, -0.5, 5.3],
  [1389402000000, -0.3, 2.4],
  [1389488400000, -6.5, -0.4],
  [1389574800000, -7.3, -3.4],
  [1389661200000, -7.3, -2.3],
  [1389747600000, -7.9, -4.2],
  [1389834000000, -4.7, 0.9],
  [1389920400000, -1.2, 0.4],
  [1390006800000, -2.3, -0.1],
  [1390093200000, -2.0, 0.3]
];

var data = data1.map(function(v) {
  v[1] += 10;
  v[2] += 10;
  return v;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data,null,3) + '</pre>');
```